# Finding values from one column that sum up to value of another column - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns A and B. I want to find values from column B that sums up to the value of column A. The values of column B are present in descending order, however I want to find the perfect sum:

```
A   |  B
----|----
100 | 80
    | 60
    | 50
    | 50
```

or it might be present like:

```
A   | B
----|----
120 | 80
    | 50
    | 30
    | 20
    | 10
```

For the first case 50 & 50 should be selected while in the second case it should be 80, 30 & 10. I want to return the index values in both the cases, indices 2 & 3 for first case and 0, 2, 4 for the second case.

I want to find those values from column B, however if there is no perfect sum then it should return -1.

P.S. Any of the possible combinations should do, but preferably larger values first and then smaller values. Although I would say chances of more than one possible combination is nearly impossible based on the data that I have

Comment: And if there is more than one possible answer?

Comment: are you using pandas ?

Comment: @Ralubrusto any of the possible combinations should do, but preferable larger values first and then smaller values. Although I would say chances of more than one possible answer is nearly impossible based on the data that I have

Comment: @AajKaal yes i am using Pandas

Comment: a sample dataframe would be helpful

Comment: @antoine Hi I have already provided two examples above with column A and column B, the data that I have is similar

Comment: This is a knapsack problem, the big-O complexity explodes. Do you only care about small integers, where we can get away with ignoring scaleability?

Comment: The values are in thousands and millions actually and not such small integers @smci

Comment: @DebadriDutta: regardless, they have a highest common factor of 10 (thousand/million/whatever), so after you divide by the HCF, the examples you posted only require integers up to 10 and 12 respectively. So, do you care about big-O scaleability in solutions or not?

Comment: @smci the no. of rows at max are around 200-250. I don't want any super fast algo, just a decent one would do

Comment: This is a dupe, see all the existing Q&A on [simplified knapsack problem for max-sum](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+knapsack+problem+max+sum) or related keywords. Some are in base Python, some numpy, some pandas, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This iterates all combinations until a match is found or returns -1. It starts with combination size two up to the number of rows. Assumes there will never be a single value in column B that matches column A.

This is an updated version using python list comprehension instead of pandas to do the summing. There's a good amount of time savings using list comprehension. Also, I look at the target value and the first (high values sorted in list) and determine the size of the combinations to start with. This isn't a great time saver in the end - see the end for an explanation.

```
from numpy.random import default_rng
import io
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
from math import comb

def get_indices(df):
    target_val = df['A'].iloc[0]
    first_b = df['B'].iloc[0]
    rstart = int(target_val / first_b) + 1
    print(target_val)
    print(rstart)
    for r in range(rstart, df.shape[0] + 1):
        combos = list(combinations(df.B.tolist(), r))
        dft = [sum(list(item)) for item in combos]
        if target_val in dft:
            idx = dft.index(target_val)
            return df.loc[df.B.isin(combos[idx])].index.tolist()
    return -1


# df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''A    B
# 120  80
# 0     50
# 0     30
# 0     20
# 0     10'''), sep='\s+', engine='python')

# df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''A    B
# 100  80
# 0     60
# 0     50
# 0     50'''), sep='\s+', engine='python')

# This creates a new dataframe just for testing; sometimes it finds matches, other times not. when it doesn't you get the total time it takes to run fully through all combination.

n=25
d = default_rng().choice(99999, size=n, replace=False)
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': d}).sort_values('B', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
df['A'] =  [250000] + [0]*(n-1)

indices = get_indices(df)
print(indices)
if indices != -1:
    print(df.loc[indices])
```

Some sort of multiprocessing/threading would help, but if you look at the count of combinations your looking at such huge numbers, you'll have to find a serious computer or distributed computing to do this. (would like to hear what others have to say though....)

This shows counts of combinations for the size of your dataframe (n).

```
n=10
for r in range(2, n+1):
    print(r, comb(n, r))
```

When you only have 10 rows, the max combinations is 252 with r=5, but when  you get to n=250

```
n=250
for r in range(2, n+1):
    print(r, comb(n, r))
```

Here's your number of combinations to test at r=125. I don't even know who to pronounce that!

```
91208366928185711600087718663295946582847985411225264672245111235434562752
```

Good luck!

Comment: The code stops after running for 2/3 rows in my dataframe

Comment: It works with what you provided, if you want to provide your actual data or dataframe, please do.

Comment: Due to privacy issues, I cannot provide the data. However instead of 4/5 rows that I have shown as example there might be upto 200 rows, for which I think the time complexity is becoming very high

Comment: Hi, the time complexity is huge when the no. of rows cross 50, idk why. But I had to put a restriction to no. of rows there. I am really happy that you were able to help me out, hence accepting the answer but would be really grateful to if you are able to come up with a code that has lesser time complexity

Comment: That's a tough one. I can give it some thought but didn't take that in to account initially.